# String array is not recognizing a value of an object and the object itself

Tags: java, android

I have a string array and I have an object called ship1 that is in an if statement which is inside an onItemClickListener. I want one of the objects values(addSpend) displayed in one of the strings in the array but for some reason the string array does not recognize or see ship1. How do i fix that?   (I want the add Spend value displayed next to "Ranger Ship")

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hangar);

    String[] ship = {"Scout Ship", "Ranger Ship"  , "Gun Ship MK.1",
            "Conquerer Ship", "Gun Ship MK.2", "Tank Ship",
            "Battle Ship MK.1", "Titan Ship", "Battle Ship MK.2",
            "Colossal Titan Ship"};

    ListView hangarList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.hangarList);
    ListAdapter adapter = new HangarAdapter(this, ship);

hangarList.setAdapter(adapter);

hangarList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()

{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick (AdapterView < ? > adapterView, View view,int position, long l){

    Intent sendListEvents = new Intent();
    if (position == 0) {
        Ship ship1 = new Ship();
        ship1.setAddAmount(50);
        ship1.setAddTime(5000);
        ship1.setAddSpend(1000);
        ship1.shipAdd();
    }
```

Comment: where are your setters?

Comment: kindly post the error message, that makes debugging easy.

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.hangar)' <== semicolumn here

Comment: @KickButtowski 
Setters are below where the object ship is being created.

Comment: @AIL 
I have the semicolon there it probably got removed when i copied it

Comment: @AIL is right about the missing semicolon on the call to `setContentView()`; you also have an extra single-quote on that line (those keys are next to each other on many keyboard layouts so it was probably just the wrong key pressed), so fix that and you should be good.

Comment: @user2900314
Its too long to paste here

Comment: If you need help, you need to do is to paste just first few lines. Otherwise how can we help you? reading  your code, understanding the logic behind it, i don't think that's worth anyone's time. anyways choice is yours.

Comment: heres a few lines
`at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at xetron.cosmicclicker.HangarActivity.<init>(HangarActivity.java:28)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code in the stack trace, you're dereferencing a null pointer, at line 28 of HangarActivity, which is in the constructor.  Look at that constructor and figure out why the object being dereferenced on that line is null and how to fix that.

Side note: the code you pasted in your original question appears to be completely unrelated to the problem, and the actual problem is shown in the stack trace of your exception.  When @user2900314 was trying to get you to paste the stack trace, it was for a good reason.